# Is there a standard API to check for line separators in Java?

Tags: java

I'm using Java SE 6.

My program reads several kinds of files ranging from dos to unix and ascii to unicode, and I have to make sure that the line separators for the output file match the input files.

The way I do this is I read a sample line with BufferedReader read() function to search for the first line separator and save that line separator to a String. This way it can be used later whenever I need a new line.

I've inspected the Scanner class and noticed that possible line separators may include the following:

```
\r\n
\r
\n
\u2028
\u2029
\u0085
```

Is there a library function to check for these characters? Or even better, is there already a library function to check what the input's line separator looks like?

Are there any other ways around this?

EDIT:
If possible I would like to use Java's standard API instead of 3rd party libraries, but all suggestions are most welcome.

EDIT:
Just to clarify.
1) The input files do not depend on where this program is running. For example, if I'm running this program in Dos, I can still get a Unix input file.
2) My goal is not to read each line delimited with line separators -- that's simple. What I really need is to write an output file with the same line separators as the input file. For example, if I'm running this program in Dos, and I get a Unix input file, I want to be able to write my output file with Unix line separators. This is why I'm asking if there's a standard API to detect line separators based on input files, rather than running OS.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The previous three answers don't really address the question. The OP wants to determine from a given file: what is the line separator used in this file?

This question can not be answered definitely for a given file, as the file might be using several line endings. This might seem contrived but it's possible.

So the best approach to me seems to be to parse the input file yourself, counting the occurrences of possible line ending character sequences and choosing the one that appears most often as the line separator of this file.

I have not come across a library that would implement this functionality.

Comment: "might seem contrived" - It is definitely not an edge-case, for example - java unix log files with mainframe responses, or copied-pasted texts from different sources. I would never assume a file has only one type of line separator.

Answer (score 2):

BufferedReader and readLine() automatically handles at least the first three variants of end of line markers.

Comment: I think this is better solution, no need hardcode those \n and \r stuff.

Answer (score 2):

I've looked for a very long time for an api for this. But could not find.

I use a similar approach to read for the first line delimiter with a regex.

I had to spend some time getting the right Regex to work and wished that this answer would have code for it. So I ended up writing something myself:

```
/**
* <h1> Identify which line delimiter is used in a string </h1>
*
* This is useful when processing files that were created on different operating systems.
*
* @param str - the string with the mystery line delimiter.
* @return  the line delimiter for windows, {@code \r\n}, <br>
*           unix/linux {@code \n} or legacy mac {@code \r} <br>
*           if none can be identified, it falls back to unix {@code \n}
*/
public static String identifyLineDelimiter(String str) {
    if (str.matches("(?s).*(\\r\\n).*")) {     //Windows //$NON-NLS-1$
        return "\r\n"; //$NON-NLS-1$
    } else if (str.matches("(?s).*(\\n).*")) { //Unix/Linux //$NON-NLS-1$
        return "\n"; //$NON-NLS-1$
    } else if (str.matches("(?s).*(\\r).*")) { //Legacy mac os 9. Newer OS X use \n //$NON-NLS-1$
        return "\r"; //$NON-NLS-1$
    } else {
        return "\n";  //fallback onto '\n' if nothing matches. //$NON-NLS-1$
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can get the OS line separator from `System.properties("line.separator")`.[System Properties Documentation](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/environment/sysprop.html)